# Clicking on image will not work

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame to create a fully customizable enigma machine in python. One thing I decided to implement early is a help function. When I was testing this, nothing would show up on the console. Here is the code for the image clicking (not all of the code)

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        pygame.display.quit()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        x, y = event.pos
        if img.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
            print('test')
```

How do I make this work? All help would be useful.

Comment: make sure the Rect you are collidepoint with is where your image is blit to the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `img.get_rect()` you create a `pygame.Rect` with the size of the image/surface and the default `topleft` coordinates (0, 0), i.e. your rect is positioned at the top left corner of your screen. I suggest creating a rect instance for the img at the beginning of the program and use it as the blit position and for the collision detection. You can pass the [`topleft`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), `center`, `x, y`, etc., coordinates directly as an argument to [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect): `rect = img.get_rect(topleft=(200, 300))`.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

img = pg.Surface((100, 50))
img.fill((0, 100, 200))
# Create a pygame.Rect with the size of the surface and
# the `topleft` coordinates (200, 300).
rect = img.get_rect(topleft=(200, 300))
# You could also set the coords afterwards.
# rect.topleft = (200, 300)
# rect.center = (250, 325)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print('test')

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Blit the image/surface at the rect.topleft coords.
    screen.blit(img, rect)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @ReedsShorts to mark an answer as accepted, click the tick icon next to vote count, instead of editing the title of the question